# Bootstrap URL Modal does not appear?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, href

I'm currently a beginner in Bootstrap Modals. I just want to ask why the external URL is not appearing in the modal?

Here's an example about what I'm trying to do:
http://www.screencast.com/t/YLWJeAwkPK

Here is the whole HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modals with Remote URL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('a.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".modal-body").html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
});
</script>

<body>
    <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="http://www.bing.com" data-target="#myModal">click me</a>
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code came from http://jsfiddle.net/f2Fcd/. I've just copy and paste it and explore it. Does anyone know what's wrong with the code? Or maybe I've missed something? Thank you very much for your response. :)

Comment: What's the problem? Bing shown in the modal actually.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your request
- you want to reproduce the scrolling? change `scrolling="no"` to `scrolling="yes"` 

- you want reproduce the scrolling bug in the screencast? (that would depend on the site in the iframe)

Comment: I don't know but when I created the html file and then copied the codes in jsfiddle, the modal did not appear. Only a fade appeared.